# Where can we ask tool-related questions?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Stack Overflow specifically bans questions asking for advice about appropriate programming tools for solving a particular problem. So, where should we ask such questions?

For example, imagine a user is looking for a parser generator that will be a good choice for creating a parser for their type of data. Where do they get advice?

You might say "a forum where programming language theory is discussed", but the problem with such forums is that they tend to be lightly visited, and moreover there is inevitably an annoying and time consuming registration process. If you want to ask one simple question, it's a big time waster to get all involved first finding the right forum, then registering for it, then listening to the crickets for five days waiting for a possible answer.

I have looked through the Stack Exchange sites and have not seen one that applies.

Comment: See [QA is Hard, Let's Go Shopping!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)  for the reasons why it's difficult to find a site.  You might try asking your question here: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking for software or tool recommendations, you can post it on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com). But note that, when posting a question there, describe **exactly** what you need: add all details so people can give you an exact recommendation, otherwise your question will probably be closed as "too broad". Have a look at this question on Meta Software Recommendations: [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/235)

Answer (score 2):

[Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) is in beta.  Such questions can *potentially* be on topic there, assuming you're able to follow the requirements they have set for their recommendation questions.